# Sed search and delete matching two patterns one of which is a variable

Tags: bash, sed, array, pattern-matching

I have a file that contains multiple instances of code that I need to delete. Here is an example:

```
!/bin/bash
mkdir /rootdir/pipeline_runs/oncology/analysis/sample_1_NA172_1
cd /rootdir/pipeline_runs/oncology/analysis/sample_1_NA172_1
ln -s ../oncology/importantFile1 importantFile1
ln -s ../oncology/importantFile2 importantFile2

mkdir /rootdir/pipeline_runs/oncology/analysis/sample_2_NA172_2
cd /rootdir/pipeline_runs/oncology/analysis/sample_2_NA172_2
ln -s ../oncology/importantFile1 importantFile1
ln -s ../oncology/importantFile2 importantFile2

mkdir /rootdir/pipeline_runs/oncology/analysis/sample_3_NA172_3
cd /rootdir/pipeline_runs/oncology/analysis/sample_3_NA172_3
ln -s ../oncology/importantFile1 importantFile1
ln -s ../oncology/importantFile2 importantFile2
```

In reality, there can be 16 to 30 of these in this script. I need to be able to sed into this file and search a given sample(e.g. sample_1_NA172_1) and delete the mkdir line and the 13 lines that follow it for all samples but this one. There are some cases where I will need to keep the code snippet for more than one sample, but to start with I'm trying to make just one work.

```
fileToEdit=above-mentioned-script.sh

# This pulls out the first line of each mkdir snippet along with the 
# sample name.
mkdirList=$(grep -E mkdir $fileToEdit)

# Removes the mkdir from output and cuts 
# all the dir path leaving just the sample name
sample=$(echo $mkdirList | sed 's/mkdir //g' | tr ' ' '\n' | cut -d/ -f14-)

printf "\n"
echo "Which sample(s) would you like to keep?"
printf "\n"

# Dynamic Menu Function
createmenu () {
select selected_option; do # in "$@" is the default
    if [ 1 -le "$REPLY" ] && [ "$REPLY" -le $(($#)) ]; then
        break;
    else
        echo "Please make a vaild selection (1-$#)."
    fi
done
}

declare -a tsample=();

# Load Menu by Line of Returned Command
mapfile -t tsample < <(echo $sample | tr ' ' '\n');

# Display Menu and Prompt for Input
echo "(Please select one):";
.
# This generates a dynamic numbered menu list of all the samples.
# Currently it allows the user to choose one sample to keep.
# Eventually I'd like to allow them to choose multiple samples. 
createmenu "${tsample[@]}"

# This is the sample that was chosen
tsample=($echo "${selected_option}");

# This greps all the samples BUT the chosen sample and makes it a variable.
rsample=$(echo $sample | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v $tsample)

# This is my attempt to make an array out of the remaining samples
# that need to be deleted, and then sed search/delete them from the script.
declare -a array=( "echo $rsample" )
for i in "${!array[*]}"
    do
            sed -i '/mkdir.*$i/,+13 d' $fileToEdit
    done
```

I have verified that I can successfully use:

```
sed -i /mkdir.*sample_1_NA172_1/,+13 d'
```

I think my array is ok. I think my problem is using $i next to a "*" inside a sed search field.

So:

1. I'm trying to make sed work with a wildcard against an array.
2. I'd like to get this where it can accept multiple samples to preserve.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the single quote to double quotes like below works?:

```
sed -i "/mkdir.*$i/,+13 d" $fileToEdit
```

What about :

```
 sed -i "/mkdir.*${i}/,+13 d" $fileToEdit
```

Comment: Yes, the double quotes made the difference! Thanks Demeter!